# Is it possible to detect a change of <select> length immediately using MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have a `<select>` tag that is populated and updated dynamically with `<option>` tags. Currently I let the `MutationObserver` change the local length variable that keeps track of the `.length` property of the `<select>`. The issue is that it seems to be some delay before the `MutationObserver` actually updates the value and oftentimes the variable is not the current length of the select list. Is there some workaround or is this the nature of `MutationObserver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of the behavior that you described. Now matter how many times I run it, the longest delta I see is always less than `1.5` ms. Is that what you mean by "delay"?

> I wanted to write this as a comment initially, but there's no way to show a demo on-site in a comment, so I'm writing an answer. If you can refine your question to clarify or differentiate the issue, then I can potentially update this answer to address it (or delete it if it's no longer relevant to the new information).

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>No options</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script type="module">

const select = document.querySelector('select');
let {length} = select;
let previousTime = performance.now();

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  for (const {addedNodes, removedNodes, type} of mutations) {
    if (type !== 'childList') continue;
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (node.tagName !== 'OPTION') continue;
      length += 1;
    }
    for (const node of removedNodes) {
      if (node.tagName !== 'OPTION') continue;
      length -= 1;
    }
  }
  const deltaMs = performance.now() - previousTime;
  console.log('Observed', `length: ${length} (${deltaMs} ms)`);
});

observer.observe(select, {childList: true});

const setOptions = (items) => {
  const options = items.map(str => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = str;
    return option;
  });

  while (select.firstChild) select.firstChild.remove();
  for (const option of options) select.appendChild(option);
  previousTime = performance.now();
  console.log('Set', `length: ${select.length}`);
};

const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

setOptions(['a', 'b', 'c']);
await delay(2e3);

setOptions(['none']);
await delay(2e3);

setOptions(['one', 'two', 'three']);
await delay(2e3);

observer.disconnect();

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it is enough for the code I have not to work. I might be abusing it a bit but right after I add an `<option>` I check the value of the local variable.

Comment: Then yes, that is the general timescale of JavaScript code. It’s by no means slow, but it will never perform like languages which compile to optimized machine code.

Comment: There’s probably an optimization that can be made in another part of your program in order to avoid the issue that “will not work”. You can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that, but be sure to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).